# How to change UIButton property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uikit

```
startButton.titleLabel.text = @"STOP";//do not work

[startButton setTitle:@"STOP" forState:UIControlStateNormal];//works
```

Why does the first line of code not work when i use the dot syntax to change the property ? And which method is better for setting properties generally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> startButton.titleLabel.text

this code return you the title of button that is text.
you can print this in log by

```
NSLog(@"%@",startButton.titleLabel.text);
```

> [startButton setTitle:@"STOP" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

this line of code set the title of button.

Comment: Thanks. But is there any way way to use the dot syntax? or i should always use set to change properties?

Comment: This is the correct answer. You should not set the text of the label directly. Instead, you should use the setTitle:forState: method of UIButton. There is no way to do this using property dot syntax (not that it matters, anyway).

Answer (score 4):

Simply due to the fact that "titleLabel" is declared as a "read-only" property, see [UIButton class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html)

Comment: Discussion
Although this property is read-only, its own properties are read/write. Use these properties to configure the appearance of the button label. I found that in document, pls help. I'm beginner.